# check if element exists when scrolled into view

Tags: javascript, jquery

Calling this script in the header of every page.

```
//If something is scrolled into view
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();

var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

What's a better way to write this so that it doesn't break when an element isn't found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the element exists.

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    if (!jQuery(elem).length) return false;

    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: that would make sense! I think my brain needs a break... thank you